# Jquery .map().join(" , ") text is not joining the comma (,)

Tags: jquery, dictionary, join, text, onchange

I'm using `label` and hidden input `checkbox` and on `.change` of checkbox. I'm getting the label text by Jquery `.map()` and want to `.join(",")` text with `,`.

Text is coming and everything is working fine but the comma (,) is not coming anyhow.

> I'm getting result ***Checkbox 1Checkbox 2Checkbox 5*** and I want ***Checkbox 1, Checkbox 2, Checkbox 5***

[**find fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/usx8Lkc5/6/)

Highlight Code:

```
$(".combo").append( $(txt).map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join( " ," ) );
```

Code:

```
var checked = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
    var num_checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

    if (num_checked > 3) {
        checked[checked.length - 1].prop('checked', false);
        if(checked[checked.length - 1].prop('checked', false)){
            checked[checked.length - 1].parents('label').removeClass("active");
            var et = checked[checked.length - 1].parents('label').text();
            $('.combo').text(function () {
                return $(this).text().replace(et, '');  
            });

        }
        checked.pop();
    }
    if($.inArray($(this), checked) < 0){
        checked.push($(this));
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).parents('label').addClass("active");
            var txt = $(this).parents('label');
            $(".combo").append( $(txt).map(function() {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get().join( " ," ) );

        } else{
            $(this).parents('label').removeClass("active-cb");
            //$('.selectedSwitch').text('');
            var qr = $(this).parents('label').text();
            $('.combo').text(function () {
                return $(this).text().replace(qr, '');  
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid you may have over-engineered your solution here. Please see this simplified version:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
    // just grab the labels for all checked inboxes...
    var txt = $('input:checked').closest('label')
        // then map that collection to their text values
        .map(function() { return $(this).text(); })
        // and format into your comma-delineated list
        .get().join(', ');

    $('.combo').text(txt);
});
```

You can see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/usx8Lkc5/11/

Comment: Dear jmar777, Thank you so much but Whatever code is written right now. That's required for my website like checkbox should not select more than 3 if 4th select last 3rd one should deselect automatically. So That why, I need those code and logics. I find your code helpful and it's working fine. The only problem is when I deselect all the boxes, texts go but comma(,) left. link: https://jsfiddle.net/usx8Lkc5/12/

Answer (score 3):

Because `txt` variable not returning array as a result, map function you have right now only selecting one element per click, not for the checked elements, instead change `txt` to checked inside selector like so :

```
$(".combo").append( $(checked).map(function(i,e) {
    return $(e).closest('label').text();
}).get().join(','));
```

And be sure to place `$(".combo").empty();` after change event to avoid from text being appended from unchecked text from previous checked.

Working [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/18ajfec8/)